# RequireJS does not include required objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, underscore.js, icanhaz.js

given code below:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '',
    paths: {
        'jquery'    : 'js/lib/jquery',
        'text'      : 'js/lib/text',
        'underscore'    : 'js/lib/underscore',
        'icanhaz'   : 'js/lib/ICanHaz'
    }});

require(['jquery', 'icanhaz', 'underscore', "text!view/module/login/login.html"],
function ($, ich, _,loginHtml)
{   
   //jquery has value
   //icanhaz is undefined
   //_ is undefined
   //loginHtml has value
```

Can you please explain to me why jQuery and text have values where other files in the same folder do not and are undefined when code executes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because jQuery for example has a define call which returns jQuery:

```
define( "jquery", [], function () { return jQuery; } );
```

Other libraries don't have this. You can use [shim config](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) to solve this problem.